# How computer adds two number internally?

Tags: java, c, algorithm, computer-science

i believe computer must be achieving it with the help of exclusive OR with   bitwise  left shift opeartor. correct ?

Here is the implementation in java

```
public class TestAddWithoutPlus {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int result = addNumberWithoutPlus(6, 5);
        System.out.println("result is " + result);

    }

    public static int addNumberWithoutPlus(int a, int b) {
        if (a == 0) {
            return b;
        } else if (b == 0) {
            return a;
        }
        int result = 0;
        int carry = 0;

        while (b != 0) {

            result = a^b; // SUM of two bits is A XOR B
            carry = (a&b); // CARRY is AND of two bits

            carry = carry << 1; // shifts carry to 1 bit to calculate sum
            a=result;
            b=carry;

        }
        return result;
    }

}
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Just want to confirm computer internally takes similar algo to do add operation ?

Comment: Read this for starters: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adder_(electronics)

Comment: Computers use a series of gates in hardware which can only be simulated in software. In reality, an addition take just one clock cycle to do everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll answer for a typical bit-parallel processor as would be seen in personal computers, microcontrollers, etc. This does not apply to a [bit-serial architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit-serial_architecture), which is more often seen in specialized situations such as certain types of DSP and certain FPGA designs.

Typically this is not the case, since for a narrow width such as 32 or 64 bits, an [adder circuit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adder_(electronics)#Ripple-carry_adder) is more efficient than serial addition as you show, since it can complete an addition asynchronously, as opposed to over multiple clock cycles.

However, the principle is the same for a basic ripple-carry adder--the adder for the least-significant bit calculates a bit of the result and a carry bit, which is passed into the full adder corresponding to the next bit as the carry in, and so on, as shown in this image:

[image: Ripple-carry adder comprised of full adders]

<sub>Source: [Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:4-bit_ripple_carry_adder.svg), user cburnett, under Creative Commons 3.0 Share-alike</sub>

In practice, however, the fact that a carry coming from the LSB adder may need to propagate all the way to the MSB adder poses a limitation on performance (due to propagation delays) so various lookahead schemes may be used.

Comment: Thanks Hexafraction.Basically I just wanted to confirm the algo taken by computer to do addition. As you said it similar with optimization like asynchronous/parallel processing.

Comment: @emilly It is indeed a parallelization of fixed width. Compare with a [bit-serial architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit-serial_architecture).